# How can i make views with this 3 table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have three tables. The designs were like

student table

```
create table student (studID int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
StudName varchar(20),
Parent varchar(20),
PhoneNo int not null
)
```

Course table design

```
create table Course (CID int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
CName varchar(20))
```

studCourse table design

```
create table studCourse(studID int not null
,CID int not null
)
```

How can i make a view which displays the student's name and the course which he is studying for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a View from a query with a JOIN, something like this should work :

```
CREATE VIEW v AS (
SELECT s.StudName AS student,c.CName AS course  
FROM student s
JOIN studCourse d USING(studID)
JOIN Course c ON (d.CID = c.CID)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  CREATE VIEW vwStudent  AS
       SELECT
      s.StudName,
      c.CName
    FROM student s
      INNER JOIN studCourse sc
        ON s.studID = sc.studID
      INNER JOIN Course c
        ON c.CID = sc.CID
```

or

```
 CREATE VIEW vwStudent  AS

    SELECT
          s.StudName,
          c.CName
        FROM student s
          JOIN studCourse sc
            ON s.studID = sc.studID
          JOIN Course c
            ON c.CID = sc.CID
```

Try this